# Reliable way of knowing when a control's life has ended

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, controls, dispose

The MSDN documentation for `FrameworkElement` seems to indicate that cleanup code in a handler of [Unloaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.unloaded.aspx) might not be a good idea. Controls also don't implement `IDisposable`.

What's a reliable way to know that a control is essentially not needed anymore so that I can run some cleanup code? (It's required as a workaround for a third-party framework not completely following the MVVM pattern).